# What does "Connect" next to component in React Dev Tools?

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

What does the "Connect" message mean in React Dev Tools:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that your component is wrapped in a higher-order component (HOC), specifically the "Connect" HOC (`connect`) from React Redux.